ESLint adding global configuration for browser error?
Trying to add the browser using ESLint globals configuration as follows (eslint.config.js) per the documentation.
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import globals from "globals";

export default [
    // apply recommended rules to JS files
    
    {
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser
            }
        }
    },
    {

        files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
        rules: eslint.configs.recommended.rules
    },
    {
        ignores: ["rollup.config.js", "web-test-runner.config.js", "src/index.bundle.js"]
    }
]

When added it produces this error.

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.11.1

TypeError: Key "languageOptions": Key "globals": Global "AudioWorkletGlobalScope " has leading or trailing whitespace.
    at new Config (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config.js:211:23)
    at [finalizeConfig] (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/flat-config-array.js:216:16)
    at FlatConfigArray.getConfigWithStatus (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/@eslint/config-array/dist/cjs/index.cjs:1102:55)
    at FlatConfigArray.getConfig (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/@eslint/config-array/dist/cjs/index.cjs:1120:15)
    at /Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint-helpers.js:346:56
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint-helpers.js:333:36
    at /Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint-helpers.js:296:32
    at Object.isAppliedFilter (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/readers/common.js:12:31)
    at AsyncReader._handleEntry (/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk/out/readers/async.js:86:20)

Any ideas?

I had similar problem. Turns out running npm -i globals (with --force if needed) resolved the problem, here's the full explanation and credits - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524936/5188543

AH - OK ... There's actually such a thing as globals ... I just assumed it was something that came with node ... Cool - It worked for me too ...
